# Human head in future institution complains about its living conditions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a short story, probably in an anthology, written before 1997.

It was written in the first person as a message from "what you think of as your future" (or words to that effect). The writer claimed to be a severed human head connected to a life-support device, one of many in the same establishment.

The writer didn't seem unhappy with being a severed head, but complained about the way the heads were treated by the nurses who ran the place. The tone was of annoyance rather than despair.  A lot of the message was taken up by rants about things being done (or maybe not done) to the heads, which he/she said must be a breach of their contract.  There might have been another story told in between the rants.

It ended with a paragraph asking the reader to disregard all previous complaints, and explaining that one of the nurses had just added something to the blood supply that made the head very happy about everything.

Comment: I guess that's one way to... get ahead.

Comment: This is similar to, but likely different from, PC Jersild's novel "En Levande Själ" ("A Living Soul") where the protagonist is a brain in an aquarium. There is a scene where the brain gets very happy after a drug infusion.